# How I show that $\frac{3^{25}+1}{2}$ is an even number.?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

As I see the pattern the 
$3^{1}$ =$3$ , 
$3^{2} $=$9$,
$3^{3}$ =$27$ ,
$ 3^{4}$ =$81$ , 
$3^{5}$ = $243$
The last digits repeated after the $4th$ term is same as $1st$ 
Therefore $ {3^{25}+1}$ last term will $3$+$1$=$4$ which is even and divisible by 2 . How Can I Find That The REMINDING Term Will  Be Even??

Comment: Please don't write in all caps. It looks like you are shouting...

Comment: Hint: test for divisibility by $4$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pattern repeats, that's a good observation. To make this more formal:

We know that $3 + 1  = 4$. Let us put $x = 3$. Prove the following lemma by induction:

> If $n$ is an odd positive integer, then $x + 1$ divides $x^n + 1$ as a polynomial.

Once you have  done this, put $n = 25$ and $x = 3$ to see that $4$ divides $3^{25} + 1$. Hence,  $\frac {3^{25}+1}2$ is an even number.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\dfrac{3^{25}+1}{2} = n\implies 2n = 3^{25}+1= (3^5)^5+1^5= (3^5+1)(....)= 244k \implies n = 122k$ which is divibile by $2$ hence is even !

Answer (score 1):

You can expand the formula likes the following:
$$A = 3^{25} + 1 = (3 + 1) (3^{24} - 3^{23} +\cdots + 1) = 4\times(3^{24} - \cdots + 1)$$
So, 
$$\frac{A}{2} = 2\times(3^{24} - \cdots + 1) $$ 
As you can see $\frac{A}{2}$ is even. The fact is if $n$ is odd, then:
$$a^n + b^n = (a + b)(a^{n – 1} – a^{n – 2}b + a^{n – 3}b^2 – \cdots + a^2b^{n – 3} – ab^{n – 2} + b^{n – 1})$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{3^{25}+1}{2}\equiv0\pmod{2}$$

$$3^{25}+1\equiv0\pmod{4}$$

$$3^{25}\equiv-1\pmod{4}$$

$$3^{25}\equiv3\pmod{4}$$

$$3^{24}\equiv1\pmod{4}$$

$$3^{24}\equiv9\pmod{4}$$

$$3^{22}\equiv1\pmod{4}$$

$$3^{22}\equiv9\pmod{4}$$

$$3^{20}\equiv1\pmod{4}$$
$$...$$$$...$$

$$3^{2}\equiv1\pmod{4}$$

$$3^{2}\equiv9\pmod{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $3^2\equiv 1\bmod 4$ by Eulers totient function, consequently
$$3^{25}=3\cdot 3^{24}\equiv 3\bmod 4$$
Then $3^{25}+1\equiv 0\bmod 4$, thus
$\frac{3^{25}+1}{2}$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

We have $3\equiv -1 \bmod 4$ so modulo $4$ we get numerator $(-1)^{25}+1=0$, so the numerator is divisible by $4$ and is still even when a factor of $2$ is cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

By definition:

Even numbers $\Rightarrow 2n$

Odd numbers $\Rightarrow 2n+1$

$\forall n \in \aleph$

So expanding your formula in terms of evens and odds:

$\dfrac{(2n+1)^{2n+1}+(2n+1)}{2n},$

Which after expanding results in

$\dfrac{((2n+1)^{2n}+1)}{2n}+((2n+1)^{2n}+1)$

By definition $((2n+1)^{2n}+1) \Rightarrow$ even number

Therefore your result is always an even number $\forall n \in \aleph$